# Google Maps API - Place Autocomplete только для 2 полей формы

Tags: php, html, google-maps-api, google-maps

В офф. документации по [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions) API все отлично описано, но. Я хочу выполнять "autocomplete" для 2 полей формы без отображения карты. Как это правильно сделать? Сейчас придумал костыль - подключил это к нужным полям формы, а блок карты просто скрыл через `display: none;`.

Comment: работает? - не трогай!